# Grub2 Hotkey OS selection

Tags: grub2

I believe the answer is no, but I just wanted to confirm that it is not possible to configure Grub2 to select an OS via a single hotkey press.

It just seems like a convenient way to navigate and I was hoping to create a splash screen of my own design with the OSes as bitmaps rather than text overlaid on the background.

Thanks.

Comment: No, the answer is "yes". https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/menuentry.html

Answer (score 2):

Just a note: grub2 does support hotkeys - although I haven't figured out how to add them using grub customizer (you could directly edit the custom script file in the proxifiedScripts folder - but that only provides access to non-linux menu entries and I'm not sure if those changes cause problems in grub customizer).

It's possible to directly edit grub.cfg (but the edit will be overwritten on the next grub-update cycle). For example, adding this text after the relevant menu entry in grub.cfg assigns the key "7" to boot into that menu item:

```
menuentry "Win7" --hotkey=7 --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain`...
```

Comment: To make the change permanent, you'd have to put a script in /etc/grub.d/ after the os-prober script, or maybe you could modify the os-prober script itself.

Comment: I just took the generated menuentries from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and copied them into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` adding `--hotkey=w`. Also needed to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards. Only thing is I don't know if the generated entries will change sometime so I'd have to edit the `40_custom` again, but it works for now. Also the entries are displayed twice now but which doesn't really bother me since I hit the hotkey before I even see the bootmenu anyways.

Comment: There must be another solution that editing grub.cfg, it's strongly advertised to not edit it directly, and as you said, it's useless, as it's overwritten, and not permanent, instead of using the scripts that generate grub.cfg. Try to use 40_custom, and to include "hotkey=" here.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is a way to configure Grub2 through a single hot key press.

To modify your OS choice or any other modifications I would recommend you to install 
a GUI app called `grub-customizer`. As the name suggests, you can do much more than just reordering Grub menu entries with it.

You can install it by opening a terminal window(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following one after the other:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

You could also look into [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/) link for screenshots and step by step procedure on how to customize.

And if you want your boot loader to to look better you could install `burg`. Here's a [link](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-in-ubuntu/) which gives you a step by step procedure to install burg.

Comment: This tool is very good, but should be used with a lot of cares, as it can be really destructive.